# PyLance raises errors due to a misunderstanding of simple logic

Tags: python, pylance

I'm coding Python in VScode and started using PyLance to improve my code. However, It isn't pleasing when it does not understand simple logic like the following:

```
if a == 1:
   test = (1, 2, 4)
else:
   test = [1, 2, 3]

if a == 1:
   print(test)
else:
   test.append(1)
```

In this example, I got an error that said:

```
Cannot access member "append" for type "tuple[Literal[1], Literal[2], Literal[4]]"
  Member "append" is unknown
```

Is there anything to do in such cases?

Comment: This is not "simple logic" for a static analyzer. It's hard for it to determine that the two `if/else` blocks have have the same parallel logic and the types should be propagated according to those conditions.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree that I don't expect such a tool to understand this, but I would expect ways to work around this or make it to know.

Comment: I will say, especially when it recognizes that the test variable is the union of a tuple and a list (meaning one of them).

Comment: Why don't you put both the assignment and print in the same `if/else` blocks? I'd also say that this is just poor coding, using the same variable for different types. Designing a static analyzer to figure it out would hardly be a priority.

Comment: The code I am showing is just for visualization. My case is much more complex. I have an attribute in class that is initialized with None and then, according to some logic in methods, is getting different values of different types.

Comment: The problem is that it's practically impossible for pylance to determine which type it actually has at any particular time. So it can't tell whether it's a type that has a `.append()` method, since the type it has calculated is the union of all the possible types.

Comment: In a statically-typed language like C you would use a `union` type where there's a different member name for each type. Then it can tell which type you're using at a particular instant (although it usually can't detemine if that's the same member you last assigned to, so you could have undefined behavior due to dynamic mismatches).

Comment: You might want to research whether there's a way to declare a "discriminated union" in Pylance. My quick google search hasn't uncovered anything.

Comment: As I said, I agree. However, I do think that it should have the option to be less restrictive. Meaning in this case, where it understands the type is a Union of tuple and list; then it is enough for one of them to have the append method.

Comment: You might want to try `mypy` instead. That seems to be the current standard tool for Python type checking.

Comment: I will look at this. I might also ignore such "errors". However, I like when my error bar is empty (without manually removing them) :)